# Validate Gridview CheckBox Checked for Multiple Gridviews

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I want to validate `Gridview` `CheckBox` Checked for Multiple `Gridviews` on the same page

I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TargetBaseControl = null;
    window.onload = function () {
        try {
            //get target base control.
            TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID%>', '<%= this.GridView2.ClientID%>');
        }
        catch (err) {
            TargetBaseControl = null;
        }
    }
    function TestCheckBox() {
        if (TargetBaseControl == null) return false;
        //get target child control.
        var TargetChildControl = "chkSelectAdd";
        //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
        var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
            if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&
            Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 &&
            Inputs[n].checked)
                return true;
        alert('Select at least one checkbox!');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that I can see here. `document.getElementById` only supports one element at a time, so your code will only check the first GridView's checkboxes. Also, an element's ID ought to be unique and so your check against the ID here:

```
Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 &&
```

will only return true for the first checkbox.

I'd suggest removing the use of `TargetBaseControl` and simply relying on the names, rather than IDs, of the checkboxes instead:

```
var Inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
        if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&
        Inputs[n].name.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 &&
        Inputs[n].checked)
            return true;
...
```